# IEnumerable<T> InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

Consider the following:

```
int _bonusTriggerCountSetting = 5;
int [][] result = new int[][]
{
    new int[] {1,2,3},
    new int[] {4,5,6},
    new int[] {7,8,9}
};
var bonusList = Enumerable.Range (0, _symbolList.Count)
                          .Where (i => _symbolList [i].Type == SymbolType.Bonus);
foreach (var bonus in bonusList) {
    var query = from int item in result
                where item == bonus
                select item;

    if (query.Count () >= _bonusTriggerCountSetting) { // query.Count () gives the error below
        _result.Type |= ResultType.Bonus;// bitwise enum
        break;
    }
}
```

Runtime Error:

> InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.

What perplexes me is that bonusList and query are both `IEnumerable<int>` but query gives an error but not bonusList. I've tried doing a foreach for both and the result persists, i.e. bonusList works fine but query doesn't.

Also is there a way query this in one step instead of 2?
The code is supposed to compare result against bonusList to see if result holds more than `_bonusTriggerCountSetting` number of a symbol of "bonus" type in bonusList.

Comment: what is `_bonusTriggerCountSetting` where it is defined

Comment: I knew i forgot something. Thanks, I have since updated the post

Comment: Give more detail about your error. You say the error is in "_result.Type |= ResultType.Bonus;" but no detail about it

Comment: @MichaelMao I do not, its the line above that gives the error. However, I have since updated it to be more specific to say its query.Count() that gives the error. Also I did explain it in the passage below the code snippet.

Comment: What is your  _result.Result? Give a code which can really run and throw exception

Comment: What is _result and more specifically what is type is _result.Result. You've got a type specified in the query (via `int item`) so LINQ is doing a cast from _result.Result via `Cast<int>()`.

Comment: How are you querying an `int item` from a 2-d array? I think there's your casting problem. As far as writing it in one line, I think you could do: `var bla = Enumerable.Range (0, _symbolList.Count).Where (i => _symbolList [i].Type == SymbolType.Bonus).Select(i => _result.Result.Where(x => x == i)).FirstOrDefault(query => query.Count() >= _bonusTriggerCountSetting); if (bla != null) _result.Type |= ResultType.Bonus;`

Comment: @MichealMao changed.

Comment: @mikez _result.Result is int[][], querying gives me an `IEnumerable<int>`

Comment: @nawfal The code you provided has a cast error at _result.Result.Where (x => x== i) because x is int[] and i is int. I also assume this is the real source of error. I don't really know how to linq from a 2d array.

Answer (score 1):

`result` is an array of `int[]`. but later in your query, you state that it holds `int`.

```
var query = from int item in result
            where item == bonus
            select item;
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
var query = result.Cast<int>().Where(item => item == bonus);
```

It obviously isn't thus the error.

As I understand it, you're just trying to determine if some list contains at least `_bonusTriggerCountSetting` symbols of type `SymbolType.Bonus`.  You could simply do:

```
var count = _symbolList.Count(s => s.Type == SymbolType.Bonus);
var result = count >= _bonusTriggerCountSetting;
```

Comment: I have updated the question to include what the code is supposed to do at the end.

Comment: I didn't realise count could be used that way. But what I need is for `result` to match against each `SymbolType.Bonus` in `symbolList` and find if each symbol occurs more than `_bonusTriggerCountSetting` times.

Answer (score 0):

`result` is a jagged array of type `int`, which means `item` in linq expression is an array of int (*not* `int`), casting this to an int will result invalid cast exception.

Not sure what *exactly* your use case is, if you are looking for any matching element in a nested array, you could do something like this.

```
    foreach (var bonus in bonusList) {
                    var query = from items in result
                    where items.Any(x=>x == bonus) // To verify at least there is one matching element.
                    select items;

         // otehr logic
    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason why my intellisense shows me `query` is of type `IEnumberable <int>` then?

Comment: That's because you explicitly mentioned the type `int` in the query.

Comment: Ah, I see. That's pretty dumb of me. Thanks.